# Correlation between GRE Scores and Profile

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics, gre

I have recently taken GRE general and GRE subject tests and going to apply to US universities for Ph. D. in mathematics. My GRE general score is bad (verbal 138 + quant 163). My GRE subject mathematics score is 810 with 79 percentile.

My question is how do these scores affect my profile for getting admission? Is there any hope of getting a good university at all? Thanks to everyone.

Comment: " Is there any hope of getting a good university at all?" there is always some hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will really depend on the university. Some universities look closely at the GRE score, others, like the one I teach at, require the GRE but only use it for borderline admission cases. There's [a growing trend](https://www.sciencemag.org/careers/2019/05/wave-graduate-programs-drop-gre-application-requirement) among universities to ignore the GRE altogether, since it doesn't correlate well with success in postgrad.